# Is there a Nodejs library that could serialize and deserialize paths (think URL pathnames) from named components?

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, npm, serialization

Example:

```
formatPath("/:foo/:bar/:boo", {foo: "bing", bar: "bang", boo: "baz"}) 
=> 
/bing/bang/baz

deserializePath("/:foo/:bar/:boo", "/bing/bang/baz")
=> 
{foo: "bing", bar: "bang", boo: "baz"}
```

many framework routing libraries use this as a primitive, that's why I ask

Comment: Looks like path-to-regexp might be just the thing: https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp 

Any similar packages out there?

Comment: This is off topic, but you should try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[path-to-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) should work for you. It is used by express and koa.

```
var pathToRegexp = require('path-to-regexp');
var toPath = pathToRegexp.compile('/:foo/:bar/:boo');
toPath({foo: "bing", bar: "bang", boo: "baz"}); // returns '/bing/bang/baz'

var re = pathToregexp('/:foo/:bar/:boo');
re.exec('/bing/bang/baz');
// returns [ '/bing/bang/baz', 'bing', 'bang', 'baz', index: 0, input: '/bing/bang/baz' ]
```